# How to optimize Huber loss?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning

One part of my learning algorithm contains Huber loss. I would like to optimize it using gradient decent method. Unfortunately I don't know, how can I determine the value $h$ for that. 
Here is definition of Huber loss.

Second question is that, what is the gradient of Huber loss ?

[image]

Comment: Hint for problem 1: you'd like the loss function to be continuous at $h$.  For problem 2: What happens if you look at each of the two cases separately?